# PHP Web Form to CSV Formatting Bug

Tags: php, csv, handle

I have created a web based print log that sends the form data to a .CSV file using PHP. Everything seems to be working correctly. Although, I have found one small bug that I cannot seem to resolve (yet).

There are seven entries on the print log that submit to the .CSV file. Two of those entries are drop down lists that are being populated from two different .DAT files which are updated on a daily basis.

The issue:

After successfully submitting the form data and opening the .CSV file, I notice that the two entities that use drop down lists are formatted different than the rest of the data.

You can see what I mean by viewing the following screen shot:
http://i49.tinypic.com/2n87eko.jpg

I believe the issue is coming from the following code that pulls the "Project Number" and "Employee Name" drop down box data:

```
<?php
$file = 'dat_files/Employees.dat';

$handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
if ($handle) {
   while (!feof($handle)) {
       $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
       $item = explode('|', $line);
       echo '<option value="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[0] . '</option>' . "\n";
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Below is the code that is used to send the form data to the .CSV file.

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{ 
    $type = $_POST["type"]; 
    $date = $_POST["date"]; 
    $job_number = $_POST["job_number"]; 
    $phase = $_POST["phase"];
    $task = $_POST["task"];
    $number_copies = $_POST["number_copies"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];


    if(empty($type)||empty($date)||empty($job_number)||empty($phase)||empty($task)||empty($number_copies)||empty($name))  
    { 
        header('Location: submit/unsuccessful.htm'); 
        die; 
    } 
    $cvsData = "\"$type\",\"$date\",\"$job_number\",\"$phase\",\"$task\",\"$number_copies\",\"$name\"".PHP_EOL; 
    $fp = fopen("log.csv", "a"); 

    if($fp) 
    { 
        fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file 
        fclose($fp); // Close the file 
        header('Location: submit/successful.htm');

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I just realized some more about this formatting issue. The two entries that are being pulled from the drop down lists are automatically being set to "wrapped text" in the .CSV file in excel. Still not sure on a fix as of yet.

Comment: Are you seeing the extra line breaks in notepad too?  I just ran your code on my server and didn't have any wrapped text problems

Comment: @LloydBanks Interesting find. I just looked in notepad and i am also seeing line breaks. If i remove all of the line breaks in notepad save it, the formatting issues go away when re-opening in excel.

Comment: Hi Jared, can you post some some of the raw data from the DAT file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing, but am not really sure that the code you show is the code that echos the data to the screen inside the table shown in the screenshot.  if that is true then what are all the option tags about?

if not true, then we probably need to see a bit more source code to help you.

Comment: The code i provided populates the two dropdown lists using the .DAT files. Here is the code that sends the form data to the .CSV file:

Comment: just stick trim() around any variable you are retrieving.  e.g. $type = trim($_POST["type"]);  You might also want to do it in the previous code block as well - echo '<option value="' . trim($item[0]) . '">' . $item[0] . '</option>' . "\n";

Comment: Thank you Kris, it worked like a charm by adding trim() I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any extra line breaks in the resulting CSV file when I ran your code.  Maybe it's because your Excel formatting is off?  Try highlighting the dropped down columns in Excel and then right click.  Select 'Format Cells'.  Then go to the 'Alignment' tab.  Uncheck 'Wrap text' under the 'Text control' section.

Comment: Hmm.. Formatting the cells and unchecking wrap text works for the entries already entered, but not when new entries are added. This is my result in notepad: Which makes sense why i am getting this result.. http://i50.tinypic.com/ofvu3p.png

Comment: Are 'job number' and 'name' the two drop-down box populated columns?

Comment: Yes, they are the drop-down populated columns.

Comment: Can you try changing '\n' in the first snippet of code you posted to '<br>'?

Comment: Getting the same result when switching '\n' to '<br>'

Comment: Adding trim() around the two variables that use the drop down boxes seems to do the trick. So it would be: $job_number = trim($_POST["job_number"]);  I really appreciate your time and your help!

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)